# Hitting rate limit for friends/ids in R using twitteR-maybe loop issues?

Tags: r, twitter, while-loop, rate-limiting

I am using a modified version of Pablo Barbera's code (https://github.com/pablobarbera/workshop/blob/master/code/02_analysis_twitter_nyu.R) to graph the Twitter follower network for an individual and those they follow. The rate limit is 15 calls/15mins for friends/ids. However, my code is constantly exceeding that.

I would be grateful for any hints on how to resolve the rate limit issue. I suspect that the issue is within the while loop (copied below)

```
while (length(ir_pol.users) > length(follow.list)) {
   user <- ir_pol.users[ir_pol.users %in% names(follow.list) == FALSE], 1)
   user <- getUser(user)
   user.n <- user$screenName
   following <- user$getFriends()
   friends <- as.character(lapply(following, function(x) x$getScreenName()))
   follow.list[[user.n]] <- friends
   descriptions <- as.character(lapply(following, function(x) x$getDescription()))
   ir_pol <- extract.irishpolitics(descriptions)
   new.users <- lapply(following[ir_pol], function(x) x$getScreenName())
   new.users <- as.character(new.users)
   ir_pol.users <- unique(c(ir_pol.users, new.users))
   limit <- getCurRateLimitInfo()[47, 3]
   while (limit == "0") {
      Sys.sleep(901)
      limit <- getCurRateLimitInfo()[47, 3]
      }

   print(ir_pol.users)
}
```

Comment: "> my code is constantly exceeding that" do you mean that you have the impression to be rate limited while doing less than 15 requests per 15 minutes window, or are you worried about the fact that you actually exceed this limit?

Comment: instead of doing an API call to getCurRateLimitInfo and wait one minute by default, you could check the "reset" information included in twitter's response to sleep the right amount of time (if your twitter client library allows). You're probably doing the 15 API calls in less than a minute, then need to wait 14+ minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your advice mef. I am actually exceeding the rate limit. The reset information you mention isn't part of the library I'm using :( What I really need is an R expert who could look at the code...at this stage I wonder if there are any sites where I could pay for that?